# This is thread-safe code?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Can this code throw an exception?

```
public String[] GetPorts()
        {
       var sourceArray = Data;
        var array = new String[sourceArray.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = Data[i][0];
        }
        return array;
}
```

Data is `List<String[3]>`

Comment: which of your objects may be accessed from different threads?

Comment: Please be more elaborate. Why thread-safety is your concern? Are you modifying the `Data` object from another thread? And what sort of exception are you talking about?

Comment: What is the relation with threading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Data` can be changed from another thread, you've got a problem. For example, if `Data`'s size may be changed during iteration, you may get `IndexOutOfBoundException`. Moreover, it's possible that `Data` doesn't support simultaneous reading and writing. (Writing may be done by other thread at the same time as you read it with the code you presented.)

You ought to protect `Data` with a mutex.

We could give you more information if we knew what data type is `Data`.

---

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#threadSafetyToggle), `List<T>` doesn't support concurrent readers and writers. So you have to protect the `Data` if other code may write to it.

Answer (score 1):

Thread-safety is all about shared resources.
In the code snippet you supplied, the only possible shared resource is `Data`
If Data can be accessed from from than one thread, and if in those its dimensions can be changed, than no - your code is not thread safe. Otherwise - it is

Answer (score 0):

It is thread safe as long as you access the Array only for read only operations (you can't modify the array adding/changing items)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to copy array in one step or not, so in this case there can be problem when an other thread removes item from `Data`, so cached loop limit `array.Length` value will be wrong and this may lead to `IndexOutOfBoundException` whe acecssing `Data[i][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Given the details you've provided, no this code is not thread safe and yes it can throw exceptions. Your Data variable is a key unknown here, if other threads have access to it then you can have a wide range of unexpected behavior with this method.